# Publishing flow in Postgres similar to SSDT

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql

I am coming from MSSQL background to the Postgres which I am new to.

In MSSQL we have SSDT for VS which  is a great way of publishing whole scripted DB to the server - and what more importantly is that the update scripts are created automatically for the changes (of course there are cases where they need to be altered but mostly does the work).

So the question is how would a similar flow work with postgres ?

There is one approach to use pg-migration but it requires tedious manual work of writing the bversion migration scripts which is not really the same.

So the feeling I have now is that it is like back on the beginning of 2K to write manually the update scrip for every deployment and to keep it in source control file diffs, very old school.

Any suggestion would be great from the postgres folks out there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it seem there is a neat solution for that, I will try it hands on and respond

https://metacpan.org/pod/sqitchtutorial

It achieves exactly that - automating the deployment of db changes ( for a lot of databases not only postgres)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but i had the same situation.
Prob is SSDT approach is like an 'iso' compare tool, it compares one database image (dacpac) vs a real (target) database, and it creates dynamically all sql statements from this differences, check, and apply.
This sqitch solution seems to work like EF migrations (for .net lovers) : it creates versions of database modelisation (all objects you need), and you push those versions towards target databases.

Comment: This just seems like a commentary on the previous answer? It might be useful commentary, but it's just reaffirming the recommendation for the previously suggested tool.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35138363)